# Full Calendar gitdownload missing a folder dist

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I downloaded the fullcalendar from this https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar then extracted and run the demos but its not working so I checked the console and found out that dist folder is not included in the git.

I get this errors:

[image]

Where or How to download the complete Demos of full calendar

Answer (score 0):

For building full calendar, you have to run the `gulp build` command line.

To install gulp you can follow run this instruction `npm install --global gulp-cli`

[Gulp Quick Start Guide](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start)